# regular expressions and words in the language

Tags: regular-expressions

Consider the regular expression ((AB)* (C(A*) |B))*

Give three words (over the alphabet {A,B,C}) that are in the language of this expression, and three that are not (and label them accordingly).

Translate the language into an NFA.

I got ABABCAAB, ABABCAAAAB and ABCABABCABABCAB for words that are in the language and :

ABC, ABCCAB and ABCCABBB for words that are not in the language. Am i correct? also not sure which language is being referred to , to translate into an NFA

thank you all , i see where i went wrong

Comment: Stars indicate any number of occurrences, even zero, as I understand.  As such, `ABC` is actually a word in your language.  So are the rest of your examples for that matter...  For an example of a word that actually is *not* included in your language, consider `BA`.

Comment: @Magma Incorrect.  Look at the parentheses more closely.  The word $B$ is included in the language.  $(~~(AB)^*~~(C(A^*)~|~B)~~)^*$.  It is zero occurrences of $AB$ followed by the second option of the second term.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Stars represent *any number* of occurrences of what precedes, including zero.

In your language, each of your examples of attempts of words which are not included in the language are incorrect.

$(~~(AB)^*~~(C(A^*)~|~B)~~)^*$

Since zero occurrences of something with a star is allowed., here are a few more examples of words that *are* included in your language.

$\varepsilon,~B,~C,~AB,~CA,~ABB,~ABC,~BAB,~BBB,~BBC,~BCA,~BCB,~BCC,~CAA,~CAB,~CAC,\dots$

And the list continues.

Now... most of these letters can follow most of the other letters... however there are some catches.  If an $A$ appears, it must satisfy one of three conditions, it either immediately precedes a $B$, it immediately follows an $A$, or it immediately follows a $C$.

Examples of words which do not follow this rule:

$A,~AA,~BA,~AAA,~AAB,~AAC,~ABA,~BAA,\dots$

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you understand what the regular expression says.

For "words in the language", start with the simplest (shortest) ones. Clearly, it is a $()^*$, so $\epsilon$ (the empty word) will do.

Next simplest is the outer parenthesis repeated once, then twice, ... In this case, repeated once you can take $\epsilon$ for $(AB)^*$, need to select one of the alternatives for the second part, $C A^*$ (pick $C$ as simplest) or $B$. Can also combine with one or more $AB$, ...

For "words not in the language", you can do the same. I.e., non-empty that do *not* start $AB$ (like $BA$, just $A$, ...). The expression is several times $A B$ followe by $C$ and $A$s or $B$. It is a bit harder, a way to do it is to come up with some candidate and check it can't be described by the expression.

There are algorithms to translate from a regular expression to a NFA, or you can draw the automaton from your understanding of the expression.